# Kafka connect - improving failover time when using with debezium

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Using `debezium/connect` which seems to be just a fancy wrapper around kafka-connect distributed version and uses `bin/connect-distributed.sh`

Docker compose config for testing:

```
  debezium-connect-0:
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      - GROUP_ID=debezium-readers
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
      - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
      - OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS=5000
    image: debezium/connect
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:18083:8083
  debezium-connect-1:
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    environment:
      - GROUP_ID=debezium-readers
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
      - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
      - OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS=5000
    image: debezium/connect
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:28083:8083
```

If I stop the current primary worker via `docker-compose stop` it takes around 5-6 seconds for the other worker to pick up
Doing `docker-compose kill -s 9` takes that up to ~16 seconds on my local testing machine.

Any hints at which configuration variables should I be looking to improve that? How low could I actually go? Could be less that 1 second ?

I need this for Outbox pattern and Debezium seems to have everything out of the box https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/outbox-event-router.html